# How to use specific parameter when using route parameter?

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a scenario where my route path is specified as `":type"` but the type could be either `"music"` or `"video"` as per the implementation (more type to come in future). Here I want to show **404 page** if type is not `"music"`/`"video"`.

I'm using `react-router@v6`

Is there a way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-dom@6` routes paths don't handle regular expressions like RRDv5 did. The component will need to read the `type` param and conditionally redirect to your 404 page.

Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { type } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (!["music", "video", ....other types....].includes(type)) {
    navigate("/404page", { replace: true });
  }
}, [navigate, type]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!["music", "video", ...other types ...].includes(type)) {
    return <Navigate to='/error/404' />
}
return (
    ... 
)
```

this works fine as well. almost similar but this way I can stop rendering the generic view part